# count and sum over date ranges in sql

Tags: sql, hana

I am stuck on a particular scenario when a employee changes his/her department.

Here are the exact details:
I have 2 tables-Department and Employee in SAP HANA database.

```
Dept_ID|Start_Date |End_Date

1      |15-Jan-2017|31-Dec-9999

Emp_ID|Dept_ID|Start_Date  |End_Date

123   |1      |1-Jan-2017  |31-Dec-9999

456   |1      |1-Jan-2017  |31-Dec-9999

789   |1      |1-Jan-2017  |25-Jan-2017

789   |2      |26-Jan-2017 |31-Dec-9999

666   |1      |23-Jan-2017 |31-Dec-9999
```

What i need in the output is count of employees in each department over time -

```
Dept_ID|Emp_Count|Start_Date |End_Date

1      |3        |15-Jan-2017|23-Jan-2017

1      |4        |23-Jan-2017|25-Jan-2017

1      |3        |25-Jan-2017|31-Dec-9999
```

I tried with CTE using sum over (partition), but i am not able to get the desired result.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Edit:
Adding create definitions and insert statements

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE DEPT ("DEPT_ID" NVARCHAR(400) NOT NULL ,
 "START_DATE" LONGDATE CS_LONGDATE NOT NULL ,
 "END_DATE" LONGDATE CS_LONGDATE NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY INVERTED VALUE ("DEPT_ID",
 "START_DATE")) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE 

CREATE COLUMN TABLE EMP ("EMP_ID" NVARCHAR(400) NOT NULL ,
 "DEPT_ID" NVARCHAR(4000),
 "START_DATE" LONGDATE CS_LONGDATE NOT NULL ,
 "END_DATE" LONGDATE CS_LONGDATE NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY INVERTED VALUE ("EMP_ID",
 "START_DATE")) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE 

insert into DEPT values('1','15.01.2017 22:58:09.0','31.12.9999 00:00:00.0')


insert into EMP values('123','1','01.01.2017 22:58:09.0','31.12.9999 00:00:00.0')
insert into EMP values('456','1','01.01.2017 22:58:09.0','31.12.9999 00:00:00.0')
insert into EMP values('789','1','01.01.2017 22:58:09.0','25.01.2017 10:00:00.0')
insert into EMP values('789','2','25.01.2017 10:00:00.0','31.12.9999 00:00:00.0')
insert into EMP values('666','1','23.01.2017 22:58:09.0','31.12.9999 00:00:00.0')
```

Comment: Where do the date ranges in the result set come from?

Comment: What if some employee `end_date` fits into the middle of an interval?

Comment: date ranges in the output result set should satisfy both the tables ranges. Like in the example since department is starting only from 15-Jan we have start date in output as 15 Jan. And since there is a break in the Emp table for emp 789, we need to accomodate that as well

Comment: @RadimBača, can you please put an example of this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm unable to test it on SAP HANA, therefore, I post a solution for SQL Server. I tried to use syntax that I found valid for SAP HANA as well.

```
with dates as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by t.dept_id order by dat) rn
  from
  (
    select dept_id, start_date dat from emp where emp.start_date > (select start_date from dept where dept_id = emp.dept_id)
    union all
    select dept_id, end_date dat from emp where emp.end_date < (select end_date from dept where dept_id = emp.dept_id)
    union all
    select dept_id, start_date  dat from dept
    union all
    select dept_id, end_date dat from dept
  ) t
)
select e.dept_id, count(*), t.startd, t.endd
from emp e
join
(
  select d1.dept_id, d1.dat startd, d2.dat endd
  from dates d1
  join dates d2 on d1.dept_id = d2.dept_id and d1.rn + 1 = d2.rn
) t on t.dept_id = e.dept_id and e.start_date < t.endd and e.end_date > t.startd
group by e.dept_id, t.startd, t.endd
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c8bb5e85eda9fdd26e75a11d02736176)

**RESULT**

```
dept_id count   startd     endd
1       3       15/01/2017 23/01/2017
1       4       23/01/2017 25/01/2017
1       3       25/01/2017 31/12/9999
```

Comment: Radim, thanks a lot for your solution. It works perfectly. I will now try to understand it in more depth and will try to adapt it to my exact situation. Thanks a ton again :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to complete this yesterday but as I had some preparation already done here are some small alterations to the [solution by Radim Bača](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572252/2067753). The differences are:

- use a join to include the department from/to dates on employee rows
- use the `lead()` function instead of `row_number()` (which avoids a self-join)
- there is a department 2 row in the departments table

[Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5dcf5/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Department 
    ([Dept_ID] int, [Start_Date] datetime, [End_Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Department 
    ([Dept_ID], [Start_Date], [End_Date])
VALUES
    (1, '2017-01-15 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2017-01-15 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00')
;


CREATE TABLE Employee 
    ([Emp_ID] int, [Dept_ID] int, [Start_Date] datetime, [End_Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Employee 
    ([Emp_ID], [Dept_ID], [Start_Date], [End_Date])
VALUES
    (123, 1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (456, 1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (789, 1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-25 00:00:00'),
    (789, 2, '2017-01-26 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (666, 1, '2017-01-23 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH
      e AS (
                  SELECT e.*, d.start_date stdt, d.end_date endt
                  FROM Employee e
                  INNER JOIN Department d ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id
            ),
      range AS (
                  SELECT
                        dept_id 
                      , start_date AS from_date 
                      , LEAD(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY dept_id
                                               ORDER BY start_date) to_date
                  FROM (
                        SELECT dept_id , start_date FROM e WHERE e.start_date > e.stdt
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT dept_id , end_date   FROM e WHERE e.end_date < e.endt
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT dept_id , start_date FROM Department
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT dept_id , end_date   FROM Department
                  ) r
            )
SELECT
      e.dept_id
    , r.from_date
    , r.to_date
    , COUNT(*) num_employees
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN range r ON e.dept_id = r.dept_id
      AND e.start_date < r.to_date
      AND e.end_date > r.from_date
      AND r.to_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
      e.dept_id
    , r.from_date
    , r.to_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5dcf5/2/0)**:

```
| dept_id |            from_date |              to_date | num_employees |
|---------|----------------------|----------------------|---------------|
|       1 | 2017-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-23T00:00:00Z |             3 |
|       1 | 2017-01-23T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-25T00:00:00Z |             4 |
|       1 | 2017-01-25T00:00:00Z | 9999-12-31T00:00:00Z |             3 |
|       2 | 2017-01-26T00:00:00Z | 9999-12-31T00:00:00Z |             1 |
```

Comment: Hi @Used_By_Already, thanks a lot for sharing your solution and for sharing your knowledge. I did not knew about the lead function. I will now try to understand more about it works.  Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below written in SQL server.

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE 
( 
    [Dept_ID] [int] NOT NULL,   
    [Start_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [End_Date] [date] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Employee TABLE 
(
    [Emp_ID]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [Dept_ID] [int] NOT NULL,   
    [Start_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [End_Date] [date] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Ranges TABLE 
(
    [Range_ID]  [int] NOT NULL,    
    [Dept_ID]  [int] NOT NULL,    
    [Start_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [End_Date] [date] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Department (Dept_ID, Start_Date, End_Date)
VALUES (1, '15-Jan-2017', '31-Dec-9999')

INSERT INTO @Employee (Emp_ID, Dept_ID, Start_Date, End_Date)
VALUES (123,1,'1-Jan-2017','31-Dec-9999'),
        (456,1,'1-Jan-2017','31-Dec-9999'),
        (789,1,'1-Jan-2017','25-Jan-2017'),
        (789,2,'26-Jan-2017','31-Dec-9999'),
        (666,1,'23-Jan-2017','31-Dec-9999')

INSERT INTO @Ranges (Range_ID,Dept_ID, Start_Date, End_Date)
VALUES (1,1,'20170115','20170123'),
        (2,1,'20170123','20170125'),
        (3,1,'20170125','99991231')

SELECT E.Dept_ID, COUNT(*) As Emp_Count, R.Start_Date, R.End_Date
FROM @Employee E
    INNER JOIN   @Department D ON D.Dept_ID = E.Dept_ID
    INNER JOIN   @Ranges R ON R.Dept_ID = D.Dept_ID
WHERE 1=1
    AND E.Start_Date <= R.Start_Date
    AND E.End_Date >= R.End_Date
    AND D.Start_Date <= R.Start_Date
    AND D.End_Date >= R.End_Date    
GROUP BY E.Dept_ID, R.Start_Date, R.End_Date
```

Comment: Egon,  thanks a lot for your solution. It works for the example scenario. But the date ranges will be changing or they will be dynamic, therefore the  solution needs to take care of the different date ranges.

Comment: Hi @RTG i have edited my answer to suite your needs. Its now using a table for the date ranges. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @Egon, thanks a lot for your response. But we cant have a Ranges table and insert records into it, we cannot know the different date ranges that actual data may have. So when we look at the solution given by Radim, what we need is a temporary named result set (using CTE which is created with the different date ranges) and then use that for joining within the different date ranges of the actual tables. Thanks again for providing your response to my query :).

Comment: ahhhh okay. well at least Radim answered your question :) Thanks for your feedback.